# Angular build library with local reference

Tags: angular, build, dependencies

I have test project with 2 libs, just generated no logic inside.
After I added lib1 to lib2 as a reference, I got build error

**'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.**

```
reference in tsconfig doesn't help
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.lib.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declarationMap": false
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "compilationMode": "partial"
  },
  "references": [{"path": "../lib1/tsconfig.lib.prod.json"}]
}
```

Added reference to tsconfig

Added import to lib2.module.ts